# Why are cookies in document.cookie not showing in browser cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to set several cookies on the client side of my app.  I have tried

```
document.cookie = "cookieName=12345";
```

I have also tried using the cookies.js library from MDN setting it this way

```
docCookies.setItem("cookieName", "12345");
```

In both cases I can see that document.cookie gets updated correctly but in my browser no cookies are created.

Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

I have noticed 2 changes I can make to get the cookies created in the browser.  First if I only set the cookie value and not domain, path or expires then the cookie works.  This part I think I'm not building the string correctly when trying to set the other fields.  I've seen articles saying to delimit fields with semicolon and some say to use a comma.  When I use a comma, the entire string is getting set as the cookie instead of just the value.  When I use a semicolon, the document.cookie value doesn't get updated.  So I've tried these 2 ways...

```
document.cookie = cookieId + '=' + res[cookieId] + '; domain=.mydomain.com; ' + 'expires=' + date + '; httpOnly=true; ' + 'path="/"';
```

and

```
document.cookie = cookieId + '=' + res[cookieId] + ', domain=.mydomain.com, ' + 'expires=' + date + ', httpOnly=true, ' + 'path="/"';
```

The 2nd part of this issue that I've noticed is that for the cookies to show in the browser I have to refresh the page.  So I don't see the cookies as soon as they are set but I do if I refresh the browser.

Comment: may I ask, which browser this occurs in?

Comment: I have tried in chrome and firefox and it happened in both.

Comment: You are not testing this on a file, but on an actual page via a server (with `http` in the url)? Because that is mandatory for cookies. Just asking to be sure, because you're speaking of a client side app

Comment: This is in a web application but there is only a front end. There is no server side logic.

Comment: So, I understand your answer correctly, that the web app is indeed served via `http`?

Comment: Yes, it is served via http.

Comment: when you wrote "I can see that document.cookie gets updated" you are talking about the output of writing `document.cookie` in the console? And when you wrote "but in my browser no cookies are created" you are referring to the Application pane in chrome's DevTools?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Oh, are you running on `http://localhost`? If so you might need to set an actual domain in your `/etc/hosts` file. (windows: `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`)

Comment: Something like `127.0.0.1 app.dev`

Comment: I have done that. I am using local.mydomain.com which is pointing to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: It looks like the conditions are all good, which makes this issue very odd. If I understand correctly, your code has no issues, but you can't debug via DevTools. Does that mean, that your cookies are healthy and e.g. survive a page refresh?

Comment: I don't see the cookies so I don't think they are getting created but document.cookie values do remain after refresh.